# Recurring signature block in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, automation, text

I need to often input a signature block in documents made in Google Docs. This particular signature block has a line for an official's signature, with his title immediately under that line.

In Word, I just make a 1x2 table with all cell borders invisible except for the inside border. In Word, it's saved as an autocorrect entry so it can be easily inserted. Is there any similar functionality in Google Docs, even through the use of add-ons?

Note: I know there are text expansion utilities, but the one I use, aText, doesn't allow tables to be inserted.